# Extracting text from multiple DIVS + DIV Styles with Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've tried multiple solutions to get this right but can't figure it out

I have the following HTML:

```
<section id="content4" class="tab-content">
                                                    <p>
    <div class="Text_Title">Product 1</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">Red Ball<div></p>
                                                    <p>
    <div class="Text_Title">Product 2</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">Green Ball</div></p>
                                                    <p>
    <div class="Text_Title">Product 3</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">Yellow Ball</div></p>
```

Im trying to extract text from `DIV = Text_Title` and `STYLE = display: inline-block;`

output i'm trying to get:

```
Product 1 - Red Ball
Product 2 - Green Ball
Product 3 - Yellow Ball
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`findAll`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) to extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given criteria, then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate overt the iterable in parallel.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input_ = """<section id="content4" class="tab-content">
                                                    <p>
    <div class="Text_Title">Product 1</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">Red Ball<div></p>
                                                    <p>
    <div class="Text_Title">Product 2</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">Green Ball</div></p>
                                                    <p>
    <div class="Text_Title">Product 3</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">Yellow Ball</div></p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_, "html.parser")

for x, y in zip(soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "Text_Title"}),
                soup.findAll("div", attrs={"style": "display: inline-block;"})):
    print(x.text, "-", y.text)
```

---

```
Product 1 - Red Ball
Product 2 - Green Ball
Product 3 - Yellow Ball
```